# Using BLE on Arduino to control multiple LEDs

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to start a project in which I would create my own app on iOS using Swift to communicate with an Arduino 101 to control multiple LEDs. I have used [this project](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/sik-experiment-guide-for-the-arduino-101genuino-101-board/experiment-21-using-the-on-board-bluetooth-low-energy-ble) as a base point.

After getting this to work with my custom app, I wanted to figure out how to make this work with multiple LEDs instead of just one. Currently, I am just performing `writeCharacteristic` to send a 1 or a 0 to the Arduino depending on which button I press (ON/OFF). However, for the new project, I need to be able to select one of the lights (select one of four output pins), and write a 1 or a 0 to turn it on and off. I didn't know what approach I should take to do this.

I don't need any code, just suggestions on how I can make this work through swift/Arduino code.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's answered in the CurieBLE user manual

Answer (score 0):

It's all explained in the manual.

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/CurieBLE

> **Service design patterns**
>
> A characteristic value can be up to 20 bytes long. This is a key
>   constraint in designing services. Given this limit, you should
>   consider how best to store data about your sensors and actuators most
>   effectively for your application. The simplest design pattern is to
>   store one sensor or actuator value per characteristic, in ASCII
>   encoded values.

So either create a separate BLEBoolCharacteristic instance for each LED or combine the switch state of all leds in the same BLECharacteristic. For example you could encode 8 LED states in a single byte (1 LED per bit).

Do whatever you prefer. But read manuals...